# What can I do for solving no TNS entries found so how could I make connection?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, tnsnames

[image]
Installed oracle sql but didn't got anything like oracle_home or tnsnames.ora so how could I make connection?

So i am expecting to solve this problem so I could start my journey with oracle sql and open database

Comment: Set `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable to the path with your `tnsnames.ora` or use basic connection by specifying host, port, SID/Service name in SQL Developer

Comment: I observed this also happens if no reboot has been done after the installation process and after setting the variable mentioned by astentx.

Comment: Do you already have a database to connect to - have you installed one, or been given connection information (host/port/service and credentials)? [This article](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/) might still be helpful.